# Rule for changing a word to a set color in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, rules, autocorrect

Is it possible to set a rule up so a certain word, such as elephant always gets highlighted in a certain color in Microsoft Word?

To put it into context elephant is a business name (hypothetical), I have set up auto correct so it is always lower case, but in the document I want it to appear blue everywhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open word

Type out a fake sentence `This is a test to see if WORD changes to blue`

Highlight "WORD" and then change its color to blue.

Then click on File -> Options -> Proofing -> AutoCorrect Options... -> AutoCorrect Tab

Under `Replace text as you type` make sure the word you highlighted is in the right column. Make sure you have `Formatted Text` selected. Then on the left side where it has `Replace` type the word you want to have replaced.

For example if you now type "WORD" it will replace it with "WORD" in blue.